# firebase login password backbone and phonegap

Tags: backbone.js, authentication, cordova, require, firebase

I'm trying to integrate firebase login mechanisms into my phonegap application based on backbone.js and require.js.
I successfully set login with facebook and login with twitter and they seem to work properly.

Now i have problem with the last one: login with email and password... i don't know what's happening but is seems login with password doesn't call the callback method inside my authclient definition.
That's my main file i call with require at the beginning of the execution:

```
  require.config({
    paths: {
    domReady: '../lib/require/domReady',
    text: '../lib/require/text-1.0.6',
    async: '../lib/require/async',
    zepto: '../lib/zepto/zepto',
    underscore: '../lib/underscore/underscore-min',
    backbone: '../lib/backbone/backbone',
    handlebars: '../lib/handlebars/handlebars',
    firebase: '../lib/firebase/firebase',
    backfire: '../lib/firebase/backfire',
    fireauth: '../lib/firebase/firebase-auth-client',
    leaflet: '../lib/leaflet/leaflet',
    barcodescanner: '../lib/barcodescanner/barcodescanner',
    templates: '../templates',
  },
  shim: {
    'zepto': {
      exports: '$'
    },
    'underscore': {
    exports: '_'
    },
    'backbone': {
        deps: ['zepto', 'underscore'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    'handlebars': {
        exports: 'Handlebars'
    },
    'firebase': {
        exports: 'Firebase'
    },
    'backfire': {
        deps: ['backbone','firebase'],
        exports: 'Backfire'
    },
    'fireauth': {
      deps: ['firebase'],
      exports: 'Fireauth'
    },
    'leaflet': {
        exports: 'L'
    },
    'barcodescanner': {
        exports: 'Barcodescanner'
    }
  }
});


require(['zepto','domReady','underscore','backbone','firebase','fireauth','router'],
    function ($,domReady, _,Backbone,Firebase,Fireauth,AppRouter) {

    domReady(function () {
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", run, false);
    });

    function run() {

        firebaseRef = new Firebase('https://cicero.firebaseio.com');
        authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(firebaseRef, function(error, user) {
            if (error) {
                alert("error during user login");
            } else if (user) {
                    auth = user;
                    Backbone.history.navigate("map", {trigger: true});

                    } else {
                            auth = undefined;
                    }
          });

        new AppRouter();
        Backbone.history.start();
    }
  });
```

and this is a view in which i call login method:

```
define(["zepto", "underscore", "backbone", "handlebars","firebase","fireauth","text!templates/loginView.html"],
    function ($, _, Backbone, Handlebars,Firebase,Fireauth,template) {

    var loginView = Backbone.View.extend({

        events: {
            "touchstart #login" : "login",
            "touchstart #register" : "showRegistration",
            "touchstart #guest" : "showMap",
            "touchstart #facebook" : "loginFacebook",
            "touchstart #twitter" : "loginTwitter"
          },

        template: Handlebars.compile(template),

        initialize: function () {
            this.render();
        },

        render: function (eventName) {
            $(this.el).empty();
            $(this.el).html(this.template());
            return this;
        },

        showRegistration: function () {
            Backbone.history.navigate("register", {trigger: true});
        },

        showMap: function () {
            Backbone.history.navigate("map", {trigger: true});
        },

        login: function(){
            var user_email = $('#email').attr('value');
            var user_password = $('#password').attr('value');
            authClient.login("password", {
                email: user_email,
                password: user_password
              });
        },

        loginFacebook: function(){
            authClient.login("facebook");
        },

        loginTwitter: function(){
            authClient.login("twitter");
        }

      });

    return loginView;

  });
```

As you can see i use 3 global var (firebaseRef, authCLient and auth) in order to get their references in every part of my application even if i don't know if it's a good way to do that.
If i try to login with facebook and twitter it works and callback function redirect me inside the new page, login with password and email instead makes a refresh of the page but it doesn't change it.

Comment: Are there any errors thrown in the console when you try to do this?

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply! no errors are thrown during the execution... and that's my main problem... i can't recognize the mistake!. As i said above it seems the callback is not called. I think is that the problem because also with fb and tw authentication the application come back for a while to login page but the page immediately change after...

Comment: @Giovanni can you post a repro we could use to check it out? A [gist](http://gist.github.com) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) or [plunkr](http://plunkr.co)? You can leave out your credentials; just something to show us a complete picture

Comment: Sure i can but i don't know what files i have to provide... my application is composed by an huge number of files... what could be useful for you?

Comment: Best would be to just contrive a simple example that recreates the error; probably easier than trying to pull in all your files. Might even reveal the issue in the process, but if not, we should be able to take a pretty good guess if we can observe the error happening.

Comment: Hi guys,
I found the problem... it was inside html template. I used an html form in order to get user email and password and my login action was attached to an html form button and my form was without action attribute. In this way firebase login don't work properly. I fixed this bug simply using a separate div for triggering my login event. Bye